# How can I display ros subscriders on qt

Tags: ros, qtcreator, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to make GUI to operate ros.

Right now, I'm practicing with simple example about listener
--->in ros tutorials, 11.Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber(C++)

But I cannot find method to utilize ros message on qt.
How can I display what Listener get in ros to Qt creator?

Please also let me know if there is any good examples.

I will really appreciate your help.

Bohyeon.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122591/how-can-i-display-ros-subscriders-on-qt/) by [Bo Hyeon](https://answers.ros.org/users/11256/bo-hyeon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi create a new project in your Qt. go to .pro and add this line:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /opt/ros/hydro/include \
```

and add your source.cpp in your project.
then make it with rosmake.

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bo Hyeon](https://answers.ros.org/users/11256/bo-hyeon/) on 2014-01-26**:
Thank you! :)